# C++ check if typedef if defined

Tags: c++, compilation, typedef, preprocessor-directive

I am linking a project to a library. Depending on the version of the library, some API and typedef are different.

There is no way to extract the library version. I would like at compile time to determine the version of this library and define a corresponding preprocessor variable.

More precisely, I would like something as following

```
#ifdef size_type
#define LIBRARY_VERSION 1.0
#else
#define LIBRARY_VERSION 2.0
#endif
```

The problem is that size_type is not a macro but a type defined using a typedef.
How can I do it?

Comment: What kind if variable do you wish size_type to be?

Answer (score 3):

Use an accompanying macro at the location where the typedef is defined.

```
typedef size_t size_type ;
#define size_type_defined

#ifdef size_type_defined
#define LIBRARY_VERSION 1.0
#else
...
```

You will need to write an additional line, but only once.

Comment: The typedef is defined inside the library and I cannot modify the library code. Therefore I need all the check code inside my project.

Comment: @MarcoAgnese Lib must( should ) define some macro as to what version it is. Use that.